# Domain of the Laplace transform.

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

The unilateral Laplace transform of an $f:[0,\infty]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is defined as

$$F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt$$

My lecturer didn't go into detail on the domain of the transform, but often it is said that '$\Re (s) >0$', for instance with the transform of $\sin t$. But what's the maximal domain of the transform? I figured that it would be the $\mathbb{C} \setminus A$, where $$A = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re (z) > r \}$$

$$r=\inf_{\rho \ge 0} (\rho:\exists M \ge 0 : |f(t)|\le Me^{\rho t})$$

But this is purely my speculation - is any of this correct?

Comment: $|F(s)|\leq \int_0^{\infty}|\exp(-st)f(t)|dt$; now $|\exp(-st)|=|\exp(Re(s)t)\exp(iIm(s)t)|=\exp(Re(s)t)$. If $Re(s)>0$ then the integral converges.

Comment: But what if $|e^{pt}| \le |f(t)|\le |e^{qt}|$ ? Then $\int_0^\infty | e^{-st}f(t)|dt \ge \int_0^\infty |e^{(p-s)t}|dt = \int_{0}^\infty |e^{t Re(p-s)}|dt$. So if $Re(p-s)$ isn't negative, this can't converge?

Answer (score 1):

By domain, it depends for which space of functions you want it to work. The idea, as you understood, is to ensure the integral to be absolutely convergent.

What you teacher wrote is: if we take a bounded measurable function, then we are sure the integral defining the Laplace transform makes sense.

Of course, in some particular cases, there are other $s$ for which the definition make sense, *e.g.* $f(t)=e^{-t^2/2}$.

You definition fits with this (up to a minus sign, I think).

Comment: But even for simple functions like $e^{2t}$ the domain is already $\Re > 2$? What about my attempt at a definition with the infimum, does it make sense?

Comment: @user83709 I edited, now it should be more coherent with your initial question.